# get sub table record in entity framework 5 code first without using "Include"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

i my application i had use entity framework 5 code first i want to get sub table data without using "Include" like

```
public class Category
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{get;set;} 
} 

public class Product 
{
  public int id {get;set}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public virtual Category {get;set;}
}
```

i need to get it both the way so it's there any solution for that

Answer (score 2):

I think, getting a collection without Include is getting collection without join in SQL:)

sure, you can

```
var category = context.Categories.First(c=>c.Id == id);
category.Products = context.Products.Where(p=>p.CategoryId == id);
```

But it will lead to two db connections. Include usually is translated to JOIN statement which is common solution for retrieving related data.

In not POCO entities with ObjectContext with tracking you can use LoadWith statement. But it is actually include, too